# How to use redis caching for desktop client c#

Tags: c#, winforms, caching, redis

Basically we have **winform** application which fetch data from **sql server** and **sage db**. now we want to use **redis** to cache those data and **winform** will fetch data from **redis cache** but i am not getting any suitable article which guide how i can use **redis** to cache my **sql** server and sage data and later **dotnet** client can consume data from **redis** cache.

my desktop client will be installed in 50 pc which will consume data from **redis cache**. so do i need to install **redis** at central server or do i need to install redis in all pc where my desktop client is running. please guide me with idea to achieve my job.

i read [this post](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/636730/Distributed-Caching-using-Redis) but still is in confusion and things not very clear.

if anyone has work with **redis cache with dotnet client** then please share know like how to start working with **redis**. thanks

Comment: Redis is used for server-side caching, so you'll need to have that deployed close to the server. You can of course have several machines to share the load (you can configure Redis with regards to this aspect - 1 master and any number of slaves)

Comment: my points are
---------------->

1) configure Redis with regards to this aspect - 1 master and any number of slaves ?

2) how could i inform redis to load & cache data from sql server and sage ?

3) how dotnet client fetch data from redis running in server ?